# Create react app setup proxy not working inside docker compose

Tags: java, reactjs, docker, docker-compose, create-react-app

I have a simple dockerized app that contains 3 services: Postgres, java (spring boot) as backend and a react frontend. Given the following docker-compose file:

```
version: "3.3"

services:

  postgres:
    image: postgres:12.2-alpine
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
    volumes:
      - dbdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - "25432:5432"
    restart: unless-stopped

  test-report:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-test-report
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL: jdbc:postgresql://postgres:5432/postgres
    ports:
      - "25000:5000"
    depends_on:
      - "postgres"

  webclient:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-webclient
    ports:
      - "23000:5000"
    environment:
      - HOST=webclient
      - PORT=5000
      - REPORTS_URL=http://test-report:5000/
    command: "npm run serve"


volumes:
  dbdata:
```

I cannot make react send requests to the correct URL from inside docker. Locally, adding a `.env` file with `REPORTS_URL=http://localhost:25000/` (same java service running inside docker) works. Please see below my `setupProxy.js` file:

```
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require('http-proxy-middleware');
module.exports = function(app) {
  app.use(
    '/api',
    createProxyMiddleware({
      target: process.env.REPORTS_URL,
      changeOrigin: true,
      secure: false
    })
  );
};
```

Any idea what is wrong? From docker, the response of the request is an index.html file

[image]